# How do I enable multi-touch on a UPERFECT 1024 x 600 7inch touchscreen

Tags: touchscreen

Running Raspbian on a Pi3B. 
Connected by HDMI and USB, the touch feature works, but only as if with a left click on a mouse. No mulitouch or long hold = right click. Device is specified as a 5-point touch screen. When plugged into my Windows machine it works straight-away with multitouch.

$usb-devices reports: 
T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=03 Cnt=02 Dev#=  4 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0416 ProdID=c168 Rev=00.00
S:  Manufacturer=TSTP
S:  Product=MTouch
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=02 Driver=usbhid
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=02 Driver=usbhid

Any suggestions as to how I can enable multi touch on the pi?

thanks,

Comment: My first thought was that driver software would be needed.  I've read the description on the UPERFECT web site.  You already know it says, "achieve touch function without driver and program download"  Having read that, I *still* think you're going to need a driver to get "advanced" features to work.  *Something* has to tell the OS what the signals on the USB port mean.

Comment: Yes, have emailed their support - as yet no response. 
I had wondered if it would be possible to find a driver using the "TSTP" and "MTouch" strings, but no joy yet.

Answer (score 1):

You likely need the hid-multitouch kernel module installed (`lsmod` should list it). `modprobe hid-multitouch` should install it as long as it's in the filesystem.